# react css grid or conversion from styled-components to css issue? a little overwhelmed

Tags: reactjs, css-grid, helper, styled-components, react-proptypes

I tried combining Glad Chinda's [great react datepicker/calendar component 3/5 pages](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-datepicker-217b4aa840da/) ((x)DatePicker, (x)DatePickerStyle, Calendar, CalendarStyle, Helpers) into a single component, so I can use my own buttons for switching months.

I haven't used proptypes, styledcomponents (so I made it a css file), or helper concept yet - I can't tell if the error has to do with either of these three.

```
import React from "react";
import "./FullCalBackdrop.css";
import "./CalendarStyle.css";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export const THIS_YEAR = +(new Date().getFullYear());
export const THIS_MONTH = +(new Date().getMonth()) + 1;

export const WEEK_DAYS = {
    Sunday: "Sun",
    Monday: "Mon",
    Tuesday: "Tue",
    Wednesday: "Wed",
    Thursday: "Thu",
    Friday: "Fri",
    Saturday: "Sat"
}

export const CALENDAR_MONTHS = {
    January: "Jan",
    February: "Feb",
    March: "Mar",
    April: "Apr",
    May: "May",
    June: "Jun",
    July: "Jul",
    August: "Aug",
    September: "Sep",
    October: "Oct",
    November: "Nov",
    December: "Dec"
}

export const CALENDAR_WEEKS = 6;

export const zeroPad = (value, length) => `${value}`.padStart(length, '0')

export const isDate = date => {
    const isDate = Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]';
    const isValidDate = date && !Number.isNaN(date.valueOf());
    return isDate && isValidDate;
}

export const getDateISO = (date = new Date) => {
    if (!isDate(date)) return null;

    return [
        date.getFullYear(),
        zeroPad(+date.getMonth() + 1, 2),
        zeroPad(+date.getDate(), 2)
    ].join('-');
}

export const getMonthDays = (month = THIS_MONTH, year = THIS_YEAR) => {
    const months30 = [4, 6, 9, 11];
    const leapYear = year % 4 === 0;

    return month === 2
        ? leapYear
            ? 29
            : 28
        : months30.includes(month)
            ? 30
            : 31;
}

export const getMonthFirstDay = (month = THIS_MONTH, year = THIS_YEAR) => {
    return +(new Date(`${year}-${zeroPad(month, 2)}-01`).getDay()) + 1;
}

export const isSameMonth = (date, basedate = new Date()) => {
    if (!(isDate(date) && isDate(basedate))) return false;

    const basedateMonth = +(basedate.getMonth()) + 1;
    const basedateYear = basedate.getFullYear();

    const dateMonth = +(date.getMonth()) + 1;
    const dateYear = date.getFullYear();

    return (+basedateMonth === +dateMonth) && (+basedateYear === +dateYear);
}

export const isSameDay = (date, basedate = new Date()) => {
    if (!(isDate(date) && isDate(basedate))) return false;

    const basedateDate = basedate.getDate();
    const basedateMonth = +(basedate.getMonth()) + 1;
    const basedateYear = basedate.getFullYear();

    const dateDate = date.getDate();
    const dateMonth = +(date.getMonth()) + 1;
    const dateYear = date.getFullYear();

    return (+basedateDate === +dateDate) && (+basedateMonth === +dateMonth) && (+basedateYear === +dateYear);
}

export const getPreviousMonth = (month, year) => {
    const prevMonth = (month > 1) ? month - 1 : 12;
    const prevMonthYear = (month > 1) ? year : year - 1;

    return { month: prevMonth, year: prevMonthYear };
}

export const getNextMonth = (month, year) => {
    const nextMonth = (month < 12) ? month + 1 : 1;
    const nextMonthYear = (month < 12) ? year : year + 1;

    return { month: nextMonth, year: nextMonthYear };
}

export const calendar = (month = THIS_MONTH, year = THIS_YEAR) => {
    const monthDays = getMonthDays(month, year);
    const monthFirstDay = getMonthFirstDay(month, year);

    const daysFromPrevMonth = monthFirstDay - 1;
    const daysFromNextMonth = (CALENDAR_WEEKS * 7) - (daysFromPrevMonth + monthDays);

    const { month: prevMonth, year: prevMonthYear } = getPreviousMonth(month, year);
    const { month: nextMonth, year: nextMonthYear } = getNextMonth(month, year);

    const prevMonthDays = getMonthDays(prevMonth, prevMonthYear);

    const prevMonthDates = [...new Array(daysFromPrevMonth)].map((n, index) => {
        const day = index + 1 + (prevMonthDays - daysFromPrevMonth);
        return [ prevMonthYear, zeroPad(prevMonth, 2), zeroPad(day, 2) ];
    });

    const thisMonthDates = [...new Array(monthDays)].map((n, index) => {
        const day = index + 1;
        return [year, zeroPad(month, 2), zeroPad(day, 2)];
    });

    const nextMonthDates = [...new Array(daysFromNextMonth)].map((n, index) => {
        const day = index + 1;
        return [nextMonthYear, zeroPad(nextMonth, 2), zeroPad(day, 2)];
    });

    return [ ...prevMonthDates, ...thisMonthDates, ...nextMonthDates ];
}

class FullCalSlideDrawer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: null,
    calendarOpen: false,
    ...this.resolveStateFromProp(),
    today: new Date()
  };

  toggleCalendar = () =>
    this.setState({ calendarOpen: !this.state.calendarOpen });

  handleChange = evt => evt.preventDefault();

  handleDateChange = date => {
    const { onDateChanged } = this.props;
    const { date: currentDate } = this.state;
    const newDate = date ? getDateISO(date) : null;

    currentDate !== newDate &&
      this.setState({ date: newDate, calendarOpen: false }, () => {
        typeof onDateChanged === "function" && onDateChanged(this.state.date);
      });
  };
  resolveStateFromDate(date) {
    const isDateObject = isDate(date);
    const _date = isDateObject ? date : new Date();

    return {
      current: isDateObject ? date : null,
      month: +_date.getMonth() + 1,
      year: _date.getFullYear()
    };
  }

  resolveStateFromProp() {
    return this.resolveStateFromDate(this.props.date);
  }

  getCalendarDates = () => {
    const { current, month, year } = this.state;
    const calendarMonth = month || +current.getMonth() + 1;
    const calendarYear = year || current.getFullYear();

    return calendar(calendarMonth, calendarYear);
  };

  gotoDate = date => evt => {
    evt && evt.preventDefault();
    const { current } = this.state;
    const { onDateChanged } = this.props;

    !(current && isSameDay(date, current)) &&
      this.setState(this.resolveStateFromDate(date), () => {
        typeof onDateChanged === "function" && onDateChanged(date);
      });
  };

  gotoPreviousMonth = () => {
    const { month, year } = this.state;
    this.setState(getPreviousMonth(month, year));
  };

  gotoNextMonth = () => {
    const { month, year } = this.state;
    this.setState(getNextMonth(month, year));
  };

  gotoPreviousYear = () => {
    const { year } = this.state;
    this.setState({ year: year - 1 });
  };

  gotoNextYear = () => {
    const { year } = this.state;
    this.setState({ year: year + 1 });
  };

  handlePressure = fn => {
    if (typeof fn === "function") {
      fn();
      this.pressureTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.pressureTimer = setInterval(fn, 100);
      }, 500);
    }
  };

  clearPressureTimer = () => {
    this.pressureTimer && clearInterval(this.pressureTimer);
    this.pressureTimeout && clearTimeout(this.pressureTimeout);
  };

  clearDayTimeout = () => {
    this.dayTimeout && clearTimeout(this.dayTimeout);
  };

  handlePrevious = evt => {
    evt && evt.preventDefault();
    const fn = evt.shiftKey ? this.gotoPreviousYear : this.gotoPreviousMonth;
    this.handlePressure(fn);
  };

  handleNext = evt => {
    evt && evt.preventDefault();
    const fn = evt.shiftKey ? this.gotoNextYear : this.gotoNextMonth;
    this.handlePressure(fn);
  };

  renderMonthAndYear = () => {
    const { month, year } = this.state;
    const monthname = Object.keys(CALENDAR_MONTHS)[
      Math.max(0, Math.min(month - 1, 11))
    ];

    return (
      <div className="CalendarHeader">
        <div className="CalendarMonth">
          {monthname} {year}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderDayLabel = (day, index) => {
    const daylabel = WEEK_DAYS[day].toUpperCase();
    return (
      <div className="CalendarDay" key={daylabel} index={index}>
        {daylabel}
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderCalendarDate = (date, index) => {
    const { current, month, year, today } = this.state;
    const _date = new Date(date.join("-"));

    const isToday = isSameDay(_date, today);
    const isCurrent = current && isSameDay(_date, current);
    const inMonth =
      month && year && isSameMonth(_date, new Date([year, month, 1].join("-")));

    const onClick = this.gotoDate(_date);

    const props = { index, inMonth, onClick, title: _date.toDateString() };

    return (
      <div className={isCurrent ? "HighlightedCalendarDate" : isToday ? "TodayCalendarDate" : "CalendarDate"} key={getDateISO(_date)} {...props}>
        {_date.getDate()}
      </div>
    );
  };
  componentDidMount(date) {
    //const { value: date } = this.props;
    const newDate = date && new Date(date);
    isDate(newDate) && this.setState({ date: getDateISO(newDate) });

    const now = new Date();
    const tomorrow = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    const ms = tomorrow - now;

    this.dayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ today: new Date() }, this.clearDayTimeout);
    }, ms);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { value: date } = this.props;
    const { value: prevDate } = prevProps;
    const dateISO = getDateISO(new Date(date));
    const prevDateISO = getDateISO(new Date(prevDate));
    dateISO !== prevDateISO && this.setState({ date: dateISO });

    //const { date: prevDate } = prevProps;
    const dateMatch = date == prevDate || isSameDay(date, prevDate);
    !dateMatch &&
      this.setState(this.resolveStateFromDate(date), () => {
        typeof onDateChanged === "function" && onDateChanged(date);
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.clearPressureTimer();
    this.clearDayTimeout();
  }

  render() {
    const date = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        className={
          this.props.show1
            ? "fullcal_slide-drawer open"
            : "fullcal_slide-drawer"
        }
      >
        <div>
            <div className="CalendarContainer">
              {this.renderMonthAndYear()}

              <div className="CalendarGrid">
                <div>
                  {Object.keys(WEEK_DAYS).map(this.renderDayLabel)}
                </div>

                <div>
                  {this.getCalendarDates().map(this.renderCalendarDate)}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="monthlyskip">
          <div
            className="weeklylcal"
            onClick={this.handlePrevious}
            onMouseUp={this.clearPressureTimer}
          >
            Last
            <br />
            Month
          </div>
          <div className="closecal" onClick={this.props.close}>
            Close
          </div>
          <div
            className="weeklyrcal"
            onClick={this.handleNext}
            onMouseUp={this.clearPressureTimer}
          >
            Next
            <br />
            Month
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

FullCalSlideDrawer.propTypes = {
  date: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date),
  label: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onDateChanged: PropTypes.func
};

export default FullCalSlideDrawer;
```

CalendarStyle.css

```
.CalendarContainer {
    font-size: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #06c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.CalendarHeader {
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.CalendarGrid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.CalendarMonth {
  font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 5em;
    color: #06c;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em 0.25em;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    user-select: none;
}

.CalendarCell {
  text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  height: 9.5vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    padding: 0.6em 0.25em;
  user-select: none;
  grid-column:12vw;
  /*grid-column: ${props => (props.index % 7) + 1} / span 1;*/
}

.CalendarDay {
  font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 2.25em;
    color: #06c;
    border-top: 2px solid #06c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #06c;
    /*border-right: ${props => (props.index % 7) + 1 === 7 ? `none` : `2px solid #06c`};*/
}

.CalendarDate {
  /*font-weight: ${props => props.inMonth ? 500 : 300};*/
    font-size: 4em;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*border-bottom: ${props => ((props.index + 1) / 7) <= 5 ? `1px solid #ddd` : `none`};
    border-right: ${props => (props.index % 7) + 1 === 7 ? `none` : `1px solid #ddd`};
    color: ${props => props.inMonth ? `#333` : `#ddd`};
  grid-row: ${props => Math.floor(props.index / 7) + 2} / span 1;*/
  grid-row:12vw;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
    :hover {
        color: #06c;
        background: rgba(0, 102, 204, 0.075);
}

.HighlightedCalendarDate {
  color: #fff !important;
    background: #06c !important;
    position: relative;
    ::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -1px;
        left: -1px;
        width: calc(100% + 2px);
        height: calc(100% + 2px);
        border: 2px solid #06c;
    }
}

.TodayCalendarDate {
  color: #06c !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    ::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-bottom: 0.75em solid #06c;
        border-left: 0.75em solid transparent;
        border-top: 0.75em solid transparent;
    }
    :hover {
        color: #06c !important;
        background: rgba(0, 102, 204, 0.075) !important;
    }
}
```

Go to https://1c31n.csb.app/planner, click top-left logo icon, then top-left calendar-icon, to see what this (and any improvements afterwards) is rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Go inside with the grid

first div (with the sunday monday...) and second add:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
```

[image]

You can play with that and if you mean something else tell me.

Also there is a nice game for grid (https://cssgridgarden.com)

Comment: I should have taken more time before asking stackoverflow..., nice catch... the grid className needs to be on the parent of the divs. thanks Omer

Comment: Omer: when I click on my Last Month or Next Month buttons (used to be arrows on Glad's version), `onClick=handleNext` and `onClick=handlePrevious` works like I'm holding it down (handled by `handlePressure`) .  When I remove `handlePressure`, `onClick=handleNext` or `onClick=handlePrevious` don't `gotoPreviousMonth` or `gotoNextMonth` at all. I don't know what is wrong.  I may just need sleep but this is what I'm dealing with now. thank you so much

Comment: Seems you have an infinite loop. Think how to solve it. I need to see the code

Comment: the problem exists in the same as the code from the question, before the css grid was fixed too.  you can also see the code within the whole project here: src>UIConainers>Calendar>FullCalDrawer>FullCalSlideDrawer.js&CalendarStyle.css https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dijkstra-1c31n?fontsize=14

Comment: isMonth around line 295 also doesn't say true on mobile, (but does on desktop), so it isn't confirming the className ternary for this DateNumber in this month in viewport, so annoying for a few hours now.  Other than that & the infinite loop, it's working as I expect now

Comment: The loop is because your setInterval `setInterval(fn, 100);` and every time you click its begain a new set interval. use some state like isMonthRuning = false/true.
and you actially can split your code to more files

Comment: thanks I just commented out the setInterval in componentDidMount (&clearInterval(this.interval) in componentWillUnmount) and the loop still happens..., I added that to Glad's code but it ended up using Glad's Date() _hour variable, so I'll probably delete it. If I did use state like isMonthRuning would 
last/nextmonth buttons' onClick's handlePrevious(goToPrevious)+handleNext(goToNext) if true run once if false stop?  You don't have to tell me how to use isMonthRuning as you expect, if you're still committed to helping why do you think the infinite loop still exists with my fit of Glad's code

Comment: Yes it sound good. Did you di that? I think that it is not look good with the setInterval

Comment: I did, now I'm waiting to make sure I _actually didn't use setInterval_, to see if the sun/moon is going around without refreshing... I did comment it out without setInterval, but still - infinite loop on last/next month onClick

Comment: ... I think the infinite loop on last/next month onClick has to do with using proptypes within the line 173, 206, specifically 231 inside handlePressure, & 385 - proptypes looks critical to be implemented well, is it not working because props is now on the same page

Comment: woot I just commented out `/*
      this.pressureTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.pressureTimer = setInterval(fn, 100);
      }, 1);*/` from Glad's code and it just doesn't start the press-down timer which I don't need! :/